# How can I efficiently compute the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series

For given $N$ and $K$ I need to compute:
$\displaystyle\sum_{}\prod_{K_1}^{K_N}\binom{N}{k_i}$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{1}^Nk_i=K$

The outer $\displaystyle\sum_{}$ is to indicate that I need sum of all such products,

for example if $N=3$ and $K=5$

the following are sets of $k_i$ = {0,0,5}, {0,5,0}, {5,0,0}, {0,1,4},{0,4,1}, {1,0,4},{4,0,1},{4,1,0},{1,4,0}, {0,2,3}, {0,3,2}, {2,0,3}, {3,0,2},  {2,0,3}, {3,0,2}, {1,2,2}, {2,2,1}, {2,1,2}, {3,1,1} {1,3,1}, {1,1,3}

Then I need,
$\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{5}
+\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{5}\binom{3}{0}
+\binom{3}{5}\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{0}
+\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{4}
+\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{4}\binom{3}{1}
+\binom{3}{4}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{0}
+\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{4}
+\binom{3}{4}\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{1}
+\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{2}
+\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{2}
+\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{0}
+\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}
+\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}
+\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}
+\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{1}
+\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{3}$

Comment: you dont' want to include factors like ${3\choose 0}{3\choose 1}{3\choose 4}$ ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker actually you can answer with zero as a valid case if that mekes things easier. I'll update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a coefficient of $x^K$ in $(1+x)^N\cdot (1+x)^N\cdots (1+x)^N=(1+x)^{N^2}$, thus ${N^2\choose K} $

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another series , can you help. Dont want to create a new question, I am writing it here, $\displaystyle\sum_{}\prod_{K_1}^{K_N}\binom{N-k_i}{k_i}\frac{N}{N-k_i}$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{1}^Nk_i=K$

Comment: You should create a new question. But not here, but on https://math.stackexchange.com. Please check https://mathoverflow.net/tour before asking on mathoverflow. And in any case, you need to explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Done Sir https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614297/how-to-efficiently-compute

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg any thoughts sir? I am not getting any answers there. I thought my problem would be cake walk for veteran mathematicians, or do they deliberately not want to help me :'(

Comment: Please do not tag me again.